# Not getting the expected result when using mysqlQuery duplicate some values

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to fetch data from 4 tables and I wrote one query

```
SELECT
  c.id,
  c.name,
  c.price,
  c.duration,
  c.period,
  c.practical_classes,
  c.theory_classes,
  e.id,e.created_at,
  u.id,
  u.registration_no,
  i.id,
  i.amountpaid,
  (i.amount - i.amountpaid) as balanceamount
FROM
  courses c,
  coursesenrolled e,
  users u,
  invoices i
WHERE e.student = "11"
  AND e.course = c.id
  AND c.delete_status = "0"
  AND c.status = "Available"
  AND u.id = "11"
  AND i.student = e.student
```

and I am getting the result is like below image here raws are duplicating. if I add GROUP BY in my query the last 3 columns getting the wrong data 
[image: result after executing query without adding Group By]

the below result which I am getting if I add Group By 
[image: result with Group By in query]

Below I am attaching the table format 
1. "Course", 
[image: table name: course]
2. "coursesenrolled" which is handling data which course is assigned to which users
[image: courses enrollled]
3."user" 
[image]
[image]
4. invoices which will handling invoice for users
[image]

Comment: Please add sample data from all 4 tables as text to the question , one or more of your joins is (correctly) returning multiple rows. You can find out which one by removing the joined tables one at a time. Also please amend your query to use explicit joins.

Comment: @P.Salmon i have edited my question with table details.

Comment: The reason I asked for sample data as text is that I could use text as input to my db to formulate an answer , I cannot use images. Also any answer I do formulate will be based on data I create (which takes time, if I can be bothered) and will be skinnied down to the bare minimum required and not necessarily all that similar to your data.

Comment: @P.Salmon how can I add data as text in stack question? if I paste excel data, it showing like sentences you will not able to read that data too.

Comment: Excel data saved as text file would be better than nothing. Normally though to get sample data as text you could run a command line query then copy and paste the result or you could copy and paste from a database dump or you would simply type representative data in note pad (complete with insert statements)..ie lots of ways.

Comment: See: [How to create table in SO Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-to-create-table-in-so-question). The second answer provides a link to an online ASCII table generator.

Comment: You are joining 4 tables, but only have 2 JOIN condtions. I would usually expect 3 JOIN conditions. Use explicit [JOIN syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) with `ON` clause to avoid missing JOIN conditions.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Yes I have joined 4 tables datas but the output which I am getting is duplicated same as the first result image added in my question

Answer (score 0):

I try to understand the question, so you wanna get the result for user with id=11, right? Try this one

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.id,c.name,c.price,c.duration,c.period,c.practical_classes,c.theory_classes,e.id,e.created_at,u.id,u.registration_no,i.id,i.amountpaid,(i.amount-i.amountpaid) as balanceamount FROM courses AS c INNER JOIN coursesenrolled AS e ON e.course=c.id INNER JOIN users AS u ON u.id=e.student INNER JOIN invoices AS i ON i.student=u.id  WHERE u.id='11' AND c.delete_status='0' AND c.status='Available';
```

Comment: But it gives two duplicate raws, total of four raws